# Strip a Mercurial branch on the server side

Tags: mercurial, strip

We have a `SOLUTION` folder (Mercurial repository) in whitch we have a `PROJECT` folder, that is also a Mercurial repository.

So two repositories: one - the root(solution) folder and other - a subfolder of the root folder(the project) (yes strange but it is like this)...

Everything worked, but one day someone somehow included the SOLUTION branch into the PROJECT repository... So all the history from the Solution branch was included in parralel with the Project branch into the PROJECT repository....

Now is a little mess in the PROJECT repository... There is need to clean that repository...

Locally it worked by applying the `hg strip rev XXS` (where XXS was the revision number of the very first node from the freshly added Solution branch in the Project repository).

But it seems there is no strip equivalent on the server?!
Every time we'll pull incoming changes in the Project repository, the "Solution" branch will be re-imported....

Is there a way to manage it on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

Of course the same solution would also work *on* the server. Thus you need login access to the server itself to execute the same local history operation on it. But for the default setup (publishing server) a push will never remove changesets which are present on a remote location; when you history edit your local repository, the changes will not all propagate: only additions to the graph will, but no deletions.

If such changes to the remote server are expected to be pushed, and this is a regular thing, you might want to look into use of phases and how to setup a non-publishing server, e.g. a server with mutable history: [Phases#Publishing_Repository](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases#Publishing_Repository).
Mind that such a workflow also means that *every single one* of the people with push privilige has to change their default phase to 'draft' instead of 'public' - at least for that project.

Answer (score 0):

kill the server repo. start a fresh one, then from local:

hg push -rev XXR

where XXR is the last rev you want to keep.